# Firewall predefined rule property cannot be modified

Tags: firewall, remote-desktop, windows-firewall, windows-server-2012

Using a stand alone Windows Server 2012 Standard edition (no Active Directory),

I Tried to establish a simple remote desktop with a custom port number, but could not modify the port number in the Firewall inbound rule,

when I open the inbound property I get the next message: "This is a predefined rule and some of its properties cannot be modified"

I have tried to set it up like this: New rule -> predifined drop down list -> Remote Desktop -> check mark rules -> Allow the connection.

but still get "This is a predefined rule and some of its properties cannot be modified"

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're trying to "redefine" a rule for a predefined service when I think you need to make a custom rule for the port you want RDP to listen on. Then you'll need to change thr port that RDP is listening on. Here's an article that explains how to do it in Windows Server 2008 R2. I imagine it's going to be the same in Windows Server 2012.

http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/datacenter/changing-the-rdp-listening-port-on-windows-server/1939

Comment: thank you for the link, I'll check it soon and give my feed back.

Comment: I have previously changed the port number in the registry, but when I go to the firewall rules I found it unchanged, and no way to change it there.

Comment: Right, because you're trying to change a rule that uses predefined parameters. Try creating a new port based rule for the port you changed RDP to.

Comment: and disable the predefined rule ? there are many in Windows server 2012 that have relation with RDP and its services. I will check now...

Comment: I have created a new port based rule for the port I changed RDP to and it worked. Previously there was 4 rules using 3389 port RDP TCP, RDP UDP, RDP services TCP, and RDP services UDP, do I have to disable them all?

Comment: I don't think that's neccessary because RDP is now listening on a different port so those rules shouldn't have any bearing on anything.

Comment: Ok, thank you very much for your help, I'll post in a while a wew question on Windows Server RDP Licencing in case you're interested.

Comment: Glad to help...